# I get "Value does not fall within the expected range." when I try to add Custom control to Stack Panel

Tags: silverlight

I get "Value does not fall within the expected range." when I try to add Custom control to Stack Panel.

I tried to assign a unique name for the control's name but of no avail.

Here's the code:

CurrentProjectControl currentProjectControl;

```
            foreach (var resource in ProjectResources)
            {
                //Random rand = new Random();
                currentProjectControl = new CurrentProjectControl(resource.ProjectCode, _projects, _timesheets, _projectResources);
                currentProjectControl.Name = (new Guid()).ToString();
                _scorecardView.CurrentProjectStackPanel.Children.Add(currentProjectControl);
            }
```

Could any one shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have found the problem. It has nothing to do with the Custom controls, its the statement:

```
currentProjectControl.Name = (new Guid()).ToString();
```

which returns the same results which leads to the error.

So correct code snippet is:

```
CurrentProjectControl currentProjectControl;

foreach (var resource in ProjectResources)
{
    currentProjectControl = new CurrentProjectControl(resource.ProjectCode, _projects, _timesheets, _projectResources);
    currentProjectControl.Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    _scorecardView.CurrentProjectStackPanel.Children.Add(currentProjectControl);
}
```